# Update user data in auth cookie on several devices

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I store the user entity in the user data which is in the auth cookie.
Now, what if a user is logged on several devices (persistent login), for example laptop and mobile, on each device the user entity is stored in the hard disk, if the user updates his data in mobile, the auth cookie in the mobile device gets updated, but the laptop is still authenticated with the old version of the user data... how can I solve this?

Update (more explained):

I store the user entity in the database, and also when the user log in I store the user data in the cookie for quick availability (I won't get the user data on each request, this is a bad idea for performance)... and also when a user updates his data (first name or some property) I need to update the cookie in his hard disk also, to match the new values. Now this is fine by far, but I have a problem when the user logged in on several devices, how do you update them all?

Thanks.

Comment: Cookie is host by own device, if you want deal multiple access, use DATABASE for store information

Comment: I know this, I mean... I store the user entity in the database, and also when the user log in I store the user data in the cookie for quick availability (I won't get the user data on each request, this is a bad idea for performance)... and also when a user updates his data (first name or some property) I need to update the cookie in his hard disk also, to match the new values. Now this is fine by far, but I have a problem when the user logged in on several devices, how do you update them all?

Comment: If you want to keep the cookies fresh then you'll probably need to write middleware which updates the cookies per request.  This of course is just as expensive (db wise) as just doing the db hits to begin with.  For the most part, this is why you shouldn't rely on the cookies so heavily.  Sure, making hits to the db can get expensive but your cookies are going stale.  If you really are having performance issues with the db hits then I'd look into a caching system (like Redis) rather than relying on (possibly) stale cookies.

Comment: @nurdyguy - If I use Redis, will it perform well for storing for example 1 million user entities at runtime?

Comment: Redis can perform very well, even with over 1 million user records.  It does add a layer of complexity though as you have to invalidate records any time a record is updated.

Comment: Also, ditching EntityFramework for something like Dapper can _greatly_ improve performance.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use EF, I use ADO.NET... last question: does Redis use asp.net session in some way? because I disabled it for my app, and also do you have a nice article about how to implement Redis and work with it for user data caching? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nurdyguy - Also why should I use Redis, when I can use asp.net cache?

Comment: There are multiple caching options available, you would need to research them to see which fits your needs best.  One advantage of Redis is that it works well with distributed systems where as built in cache only work on that one server.  So if you are running behind a load balancer then Redis can still work where as some other options won't.